# How to create an audio file from a Pcap file with Tshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark, voip, rtp, tshark

I want to make audio data from a Pcap file with Tshark.
I have successfully created audio data from a Pcap file using Wireshark in RTP analysis function.
This Pcap file is created from a VoIP phone conversation.
Next time I want to do the same thing with Tshark.
What command would do that?

I read the Tshark manual to find out how.
but couldn't find it.
do i need any tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, extracting the RTP packets from PCAP file is possible with **tshark** together with shell tools **tr** and **xxd**, but then you might need other tools to convert to an audio format.

If you have a single call recording in the pcap, so all rtp packets belong to it, try with:

```
tshark -n -r call.pcap -2 -R rtp -T fields -e rtp.payload | tr -d '\n',':' | xxd -r -ps >call.rtp
```

If the pcap has the recordings from many calls, then you have to identify the calls and their RTP streams by source/destination IPs or SSRC and build the filter accordingly, for example if **SSRC** is **0x7f029328**:

```
tshark -n -r call.pcap -2 -R rtp -R "rtp.ssrc == 0x7f029328" -T fields -e rtp.payload | tr -d '\n',':' | xxd -r -ps >call.rtp
```

Tools like **sox** or **ffmpeg** can be used to convert from **call.rtp** file to **wav** format, depending on the codec that was used in the call. If the codec was **G711u** (**PCMU**) with sample rate **8000**:

```
sox -t ul -r 8000 -c 1 call.rtp call.wav
```

The audio formats supported by **sox** are listed by **sox -h**. The **ffmpeg** might be needed for codecs such as **G729** or **G722**, example for **G722** with sample rate **16000**:

```
ffmpeg -f g722 -i call.rtp -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 call.wav
```

These guidelines are from some brief notes I made during the past when I had similar needs, hope they are good and still valid nowadays, or at least provide the right direction to explore further.